# Excel/Word Equations using oMath.BuildUp method?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, equation

I am trying to automate process of generating Equations in Microsoft Word 2010 using VBA and inserting those into Excel since it doesnt support oMath object. Problem lies in oMath.BuildUp method. It doesnt interpret stuff like \sqrt, \times, \delta in the same way that it is interpreted when entered by hand.

For example entering code *Celsius = \sqrt(x+y) + sin(5/9 \times (Fahrenheit – 23 (\delta)^2))* into Equation will give this result 
http://i43.tinypic.com/10xc7zp.jpg
which is fine.

But when using macro VBA or recording macro this Method is not working as it should be and it gives result like this:
http://i42.tinypic.com/29c5geg.png. Stuff like \sqrt, \times, \delta is ignored. Why? Here is macro that I used to generate second picture.

```
    Sub genEQ()
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath 
    Set objRange = Selection.Range
    objRange.Text = "Celsius = \sqrt(x+y) + sin(5/9 \times (Fahrenheit – 23 (\delta)^2))"
    Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
    Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
    objEq.BuildUp
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it just doesn't work that way. You could do your own math autocorrect substitution, e.g. using something based on this:

```
Function mathSubstitute(s As String) As String
Const bslash As String = "\"
Dim a() As String
Dim sout As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sac As String
sout = ""
If s <> "" Then
  a = Split(s, bslash)
  sout = a(LBound(a))
  For i = LBound(a) + 1 To UBound(a)
    Debug.Print a(i)
    For j = 1 To Len(a(i))
      On Error Resume Next
      sac = Application.OMathAutoCorrect.Entries(bslash & Left(a(i), j)).Value
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        sout = sout & sac & Mid(a(i), j + 1)
        Exit For
      Else
        sac = ""
        Err.Clear
      End If
    Next
    If sac = "" Then sout = sout & bslash & a(i)
    Debug.Print sout
  Next
End If
On Error GoTo 0
mathSubstitute = sout
End Function
```

and change your code to

```
objRange.Text = mathSubstitute("Celsius = \sqrt(x+y) + sin(5/9 \times (Fahrenheit – 23 (\delta)^2))")
```

AFAICS the use of "\" to escape special characters such as [ still works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Repeat it twice, it will solve your problem.

```
objEq.BuildUp
objEq.BuildUp
```