# How can I edit/insert Mathtype equation objects with a VBA macro in MS-word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mathtype

I want to insert or edit **Mathtype equations** with **VBA macro** in **MS-Word**.

Sometimes We have several equations in a MS-word document and need edit them with a VBA macro.

For example: we have to take some changes in overall of our MS-Word document.
That changes are separable by document's paragraph styles and we can do format edition for each paragraph style, and same for all Mathtype objects whose their paragraph has that style.
We want write a VBA macro to do that. but the problem is in:

"**How we can edit formatting of Mathtype equation objects with a VBA macro coding in MS-Word document?**"

Thanks everybody & M.R "Maarten Van Stam"'s guidance.

Comment: By writing some code? The question as it stands is too broad and risks to be closed. You need to be more specific about the problem you're facing.

Comment: Of course. I looking up the way of editing and insert Mathtype object with VBA macro, of course by writing a code. Sir,  how can i have made this question more specific and reach to that way i'm looking about?

Comment: you can look into the [`Document.OMaths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196821.aspx) collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068212/excel-word-equations-using-omath-buildup-method

Comment: Thank you sir, but that's not my answer. in that topic presented a for work with MS-Word equations, but please be careful sir. I'm saying about MathType equation. Are you familiar with Mathtype? I'm looking for a way for work with Mathtype equations with VBA.

Comment: There is a MathType SDK that most likely has everything you need. Please note that the MathType SDK is free, and offered without technical support. http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/default.htm

Comment: Thank you. please guide me how can use that (I was download MathTypeSDK6.9) for editing Mathtype equations are in MS-Word document, by VBA macro coding.

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer? If not, I have an answer which I can post if you want...