# Is it possible to change the style of an "Equation 3" in Word, using a VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with a lot of equations in the old format ("Equation 3.0").
I have found how to open them with a VBA macro, but I've not found a way to actually edit them with a VBA.

What I really want is to apply the style "Text" to the whole equation. Style "Text" .

[image: see image]

I can do manually, but there are hundreds of those. I'm thus looking for a VBA.

If you can help me, it would be great !

Comment: Try to record a VBA macro that records the commands your are issuing. Then modify it as needed.

Comment: take a look at this thread. It seems to deal with the sme problem, but not clear if an answer was found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458851/how-can-i-edit-insert-mathtype-equation-objects-with-a-vba-macro-in-ms-word?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks Paul. I obviously tried that before to ask the question, but without success.

Comment: Thanks Variatus. I will have a look to that. At first glance, it seems a little complex for my computional skills, but that's a good challenge.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion at the thread Variatus linked would apply here too (that is, use the MathType SDK), and would help but the equations in the end would be MathType equations, not "Microsoft Equation Editor 3" equations.